# How to remove Cloud Firestore field type specifiers when using REST API?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I totally made up the name "type specifiers." What I mean is the `stringValue` key in front of a value. Usually I would expect a more-standard response: `"name" : "name_here"`.

```
{
 "fields": {
  "name": {
   "stringValue": "name_here"
  }
 }
}
```

Is it possible to remove those when making a `GET` call?

*More importantly*, it be nice to understand why it's structured like it is. Even for `POST`-ing data? The easy answer is probably because Cloud Firestore, unlike Realtime Database, needs to know the specific types, but what are all the deeper reasons? Is there an "official" name for formatting like this where I could do more research?

For example, is the reasoning any related to [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)? Is there a way to request a protobuf instead of JSON?

Schema:
[image]

Comment: The question is a bit unclear but the reason that your Firebase structure looks that way is because... you put it there. There is no schema or pre-determined structures in a NoSQL database; only key: value pairs. In the structure above the key stringValue as a value of name_here. *name* is the parent key to that child node and *fields* is the parent key to the *name* key. If you are wondering how it got that way, post your code and we will take a look.

Comment: @Jay I would expect it to be `"name" : "name_here"` instead it's `"name": { "stringValue": "name_here" }` when making a GET call. I did not "create that schema," I created `"name" : "name_here"`. This is `Cloud Firestore` NOT `Realtime Database`. Unless I set it up wrong, this is how it works, by standard. I used the Google APIs Explorer to make the GET call.

Comment: I don't believe Firestore would add that key directly as it's still key: value pairs and key names are up to you. Can you post your code that wrote that node so we can take a look?

Comment: @Jay Are you currently using Firestore? Or have? I could be doing something crazy but I'm just doing standard stuff. I uploaded screenshots.

Comment: Yes I am. Where's your code that creates that data? *please* don't post images of code or Firebase structures in your questions. See [Don't Use Screenshots](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: @Jay I created the data by just using the Firestore console (as it appears in the screenshot). The data is retrieved using the Google APIs Explorer: `GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{project_id}/databases/(default)/documents/sessions/LAHXFvvv9KvYMqw8e29C`. I have typed 0 code, all Google GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to remove those when making a GET call?

In short No. The Firestore REST API GET returns an instance of Document. 
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents#Document

```
{
  "name": string,
  "fields": {
    string: {
      object(Value)
    },
    ...
  },
  "createTime": string,
  "updateTime": string,
}
```

Regarding the "Protocol Buffer": When the data is deserialized you could just have a function to convert into the structure you wish to use, e.g. probably using the protocol buffers if you wish but as there appear to be libraries for SWIFT, OBJECTIVE-C, ANDROID, JAVA, PYTHON, NODE.JS, GO maybe you won’t need to use the REST API and craft a Protocol Buffer.

Hopefully address your “More Importantly” comment:

As you eluded to in your question Firestore has a different data model to the Realtime Database.
Realtime database data model allows JSON objects with the schema and keywords as you want to define it.
As you point out, the Firestore data model uses predefined schemas, in that respect some of the keywords and structure cannot be changed.

The Cloud Firestore Data Model is described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Effectively the data model is / where a document can contain a subcollection and the keywords “name”, “fields”, “createdTime”, “upTime” are in a Firestore document (a pre-defined JSON document schema).
A successful the Firestore REST API  GET request results in a Document instance which could contain collection of documents or a single document. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/. Also the API discovery document helps give some detail about the api:
https://firestore.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta1

An example REST API URL structure is of the form:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<yourprojectid>/databases/(default)/documents/<collectionName>/<documentID>
```

It is possible to mask certain fields in a document but still the Firestore Document schema will persist. See the three examples GET:

- collection https://pastebin.com/98qByY7n
- document https://pastebin.com/QLwZFGgF
- document with mask https://pastebin.com/KA1cGX3k

Looking at another example, the REST API  to run Queries
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery
the response body is of the form:

```
{
  "transaction": string,
  "document": {
    object(Document)
  },
  "readTime": string,
  "skippedResults": number,
}
```

In summary:

The Realtime database REST API will return the JSON for the object according to the path/nodes as per your “more-standard response”.

The Firestore REST API returns a specific Firestore predefined response structure.

There API libraries available for several language so maybe it’s not necessary to use the REST API and craft your own Protocol Buffer but if you needed to you it’s probably feasible.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why somebody just say that you can't and don't try think some solution for help! Seriously that this is a really problem solver?

Anyway, I created a script that will help you (maybe it's late now hahaha).

The script encode json and after replace it as string to modify and remove Google type fields (low process).

It's a simple code, I know that you can improve it if necessary!

WARNING!!

Maybe you will have problems with values that contain '{}' or '[]'. This can be solved with a foreach that convert all strings that contains this elements in other char (like '◘' or '♦', some char that you know that doesn't will be in value.

Ex.: Hi {Lorena}! ------> Hi ◘Lorena♦!

After the process, convert again to '{}' or '[]'

YOU CAN'T HAVE FIELDS WITH THE SAME NAME THAT GOOGLE FIELDS

Ex.: stringValue, arrayValue, etc

You can see and download the script in this link:
https://github.com/campostech/scripts-helpers/blob/master/CLOUD%20STORE%20JSON%20FIELDS%20REMOVER/csjfr.php